# South Park: The Stick of Truth: Making my Rumble move the mouse

Tags: controllers, south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I have a Logitech Rumble Gamepad F510 which I'm pretty used to, however, The Stick of Truth only comes with support for the Xbox 360 controller. Since the game requires a mouse to interact and talk, does anyone know any current way of setting mouse bindings on a Windows PC? The official Logitech Gaming Software is there, but it only allows for keyboard bindings and mouse clicks. Or are there really any keyboard controls that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I played this on a gamepad and I don't remember having to use the mouse at all. What problems are you having, exactly?

Comment: Like when you talk to characters, it gives you options to do stuff, and you have to hover and click to set them.

Comment: Cartman says: Did you say 'Douchebag'? and it gives options to say Yes or No.

Comment: On the Xbox 360 though, Stick of Truth does support doing this without a mouse. But like I said in the question, I have a Logitech Rumble Gamepad and I'm not really investing money in the Xbox 360 controller just for this one game.

Comment: I used a Dualshock 3 (with the BetterDS3 tool) and I think that worked ok. Have you tried flipping between XInput and DirectInput on your controller? It may be that the game only works in one of those modes.

Comment: Ill try that but whats BetterDS3!

Comment: BetterDS3 is (basically) an application to let you use a PS3 controller on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 510 has a switch on the bottom to toggle X360 compatibility mode. 
Southpark should work after toggling it to the "X" setting.

Comment: Thanks! Since I was configuring with the Logitech Profiler (which only works in D mode), I had forgotten to switch it back. Silly me.